# Delete E-Mail that is saved as msg file using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

having a *.MSG file (created from MS Outlook by Drag & Drop outside the application). When opening the file I would like to delete the msg file from outlook, to have same behaiviour like the "delete" button when working with ordinary mails in Outlook.

Running "delete" will close the window but does not delete the msg file as I want to.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do - when you open an MSG file, Outlook creates a temporary message in the primary store and copies the data from MSG file.

There is no way to check if any given message was open from an MSG file and what the MSG file name is.